# Banking Account in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I need some clarification on inheritance concept for school.

I have a super class called Account
With Attributes: Name, acctNum and balance
With methods: deposit() and withdraw()

And another class called Saving which is a subclass of Account
With Attributes: interestRate (with fixed value of 2%)
With Methods: interestPerYear() and methodB()

And another class called FixedDeposit (This is the one I am not sure about)
With Attributes: interestRate (with fixed value of 4%)
With Methods: interestPerYear() and methodB()

So can the fixedDeposit class be a subclass of Saving so that it can inherit the 2 methods interestPerYear() and methodB()? If so how to make the interestRate value used for fixedDeposit to be 4% instead?

interestPerYear() is calculated by balance x interestRate.

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way to answer that is to use the "is a" trick. A related example is two classes Mammal and Dog. A Dog is a Mammal therefore Dog can inherit from Mammal. In your case, is a Saving a FixedDeposit? Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is *overriding*: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: Well, if the attribute is inheritable (that is, not `private` nor `final`), you can simply give it a different value in the constructor of the subclass.

Comment: This is a very good question that most beginning cs people have. Inheritance and the whole super/sub class concept is confusing at first. I wish you luck.

Comment: It's actually hard to tell from what you described (I can't because I don't know how FixedDeposit and Savings relate to each other). Try looking at it from real-world relations: if `FixedDeposit` is a type of `Saving`, then it can extend `Saving`. Otherwise, since there are same methods, then probably there is some common ancestor, which we'll name, for example, `Joe`(because it'll be shorter this way), and you'll have your `FixedDeposit extends Joe` and `Savings extends Joe`.

Comment: Kaz, if one of the provided answers solved your problem, then please mark it as *accepted* (tick mark on the left) so your question will be marked solved. Check out the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

fixedDeposit can not be a subclass of savings because a fixed deposit account is not a savings account. When dealing with super and sub classes, only extend when the sub class can be related to the super class. My professor gave my cs class this analogy.

You have the super class vehicle. All vehicles have wheels. However, you have cars, trucks, and motorcycles. Car can not extend truck, because a car is not a truck. Cars also have sub classes sedans and suv's. An suv is not a motorcycle, therefore suv can not extend motorcycle.

I hope that this answer is helpful and that you now know more about super/sub classes.

Comment: Google says *A fixed deposit account is an investment account and a type of savings account in which money is deposited for a stated period of time...* Meaning that your statement is wrong.

Comment: xD my bad. I'm a programmer, not an accountant. I should have researched that first. You can -1 my answer if it helps you feel better!

Comment: ...or you can improve it, instead. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> So can the fixedDeposit class be a subclass of Saving [...]?

The answer mainly depends on whether or not a fixed deposit account is some kind of savings account. To be honest, I don't know about that. From what you are describing, it looks as if the fixed deposit account could extend both, the savings account or the generic account.

> If so how to make the interestRate value used for fixedDeposit to be 4% instead?

There are different approaches to this. I will outline some.

### Option A

Let `Saving` and `FixedDeposit` both be a direct subclass of `Account`. We could model that as follows:

```
public class Account {

    private String name;
    private int acctNum;
    private float balance;
    private float interestRate;

    public Account(int acctNum, String name) {
        this.acctNum = acctNum;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = 0.0;
        this.interestRate = 0.0;
    }

    public float interestPerYear() {
        return balance * interestRate;
    }

    public void deposit(float amount) { /*...*/ }
    public void withdraw(float amount) { /*...*/ }
    public void methodB() { /*...*/ }
}
```

Here, all the methods required for `Account` as well as `Saving` and `FixedDeposit` are already present. This makes sense, because it seems that the formula for `interestPerYear()` is always the same. The default `Account` will have no interest rate as per `this.interestRate = 0.0;` in the constructor. Note that this line is not required, the declaration of `interestRate` further up will automatically set it to `0.0`, that's how Java works (some other languages don't), but I like to be explicit.

Now on to the other classes:

```
public class Saving extends Account {

    public Saving(int acctNum, String name) {
        super(acctNum, name);
        this.interestRate = 2.0;
    }
}

public class FixedDeposit extends Account {

    public FixedDeposit(int acctNum, String name) {
        super(acctNum, name);
        this.interestRate = 4.0;
    }
}
```

The `super()` call (which has to be the first thing you do in your constructor) will execute `Account`'s constructor. I'm assuming every account needs to have a number and name. Then, we set the `interestRate` to the specific amount for the type of account. That's all it takes.

### Option B

You could just as well make `FixedDeposit` extend `Saving` instead and leave everything else the same:

```
public class FixedDeposit extends Saving {

    public FixedDeposit(int acctNum, String name) {
        super(acctNum, name);
        this.interestRate = 4.0;
    }
}
```

What would happen is that `interestRate` would first be set to `0.0` (due to the implementation in `Account`), then the call to `super()` will execute `Saving`'s ctor, setting `interestRate` to `2.0`. However, `FixedDeposit`'s ctor will then set it to `4.0`. Voila.

### Option C

Another way (and the way I would probably go about it) is to add the `interestRate` as an argument in `Account`'s ctor, like so:

```
public Account(int acctNum, String name, float interestRate) {
    this.acctNum = acctNum;
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = 0.0;
    this.interestRate = interestRate;
}
```

This way, the ctors of `FixedDeposit` and `Saving` can be written like so:

```
public Saving(int acctNum, String name) {
    super(acctNum, name, 2.0); // or 4.0 for FixedDeposit
}
```

### Option D

We could simplify it further by putting away with the `Saving` and `FixedDeposit` classes entirely, as they don't seem to add anything right now. Instead, you could use the `Account` class for all accounts:

```
Account saving = new Account(8172, "Jon Doe", 2.0);
Account fixedD = new Account(8184, "Li Ping", 4.0);
```

In the end, only you know what architecture fits your project.

### But what if...

You might be wondering: *"But what if there is a whole new type of account with a different formula for the interest rate?"*

That's where **[overriding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)** comes in handy. Let's stick with Option A from above. We could then implement the new type of account like this:

```
public class GenerousAccount extends Account {

    public GenerousAccount(int acctNum, String name) {
        super(acctNum, name);
        this.interestRate = 6.0;
    }

    public float interestPerYear() {
        return balance * 2 * interestRate; // Twice as much! Yay!
    }

}
```

Here, we implement `interestPerYear()`, even though it already exist in `Account`. What that does is when you call the method on an Object of type `GenerousAccount`, Java will execute the version of the method it found in `GenerousAccount`, giving double the interest rate. In contrast, `Saving` and `FixedDeposit` don't have such a method, so Java will go up the inheritance chain until it finds such a method (which it will do in `Account`) and use that.

Hope this helps.